# A necessary and sufficient condition for a symmetric matrix to be positive semidefinite in terms of its Schur complement

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices, schur-complement

According to the Wikipedia article [*Schur complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), if $X$ is a symmetric matrix of real numbers given by $X = \begin{bmatrix}
A &B\\
B^T &C
\end{bmatrix}$, then $X \succeq0$ (i.e. $X$ is positive semidefinite) iff the following conditions hold:
\begin{align*}
A&\succeq 0\\
C-B^TA^gB&\succeq0\\
(I-AA^g)B&=0\tag{*}
\end{align*}
where $A^g$ denotes the [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) of $A$.

I've read somewhere that there is an interpretation of the third condition (the one marked with an asterisk) in terms of $A$'s column space. (Perhaps that $(*)$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{R}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A)$, i.e. that $B$'s column space is contained in $A$'s column space?)

How can $(*)$ be stated in terms of $A$'s column space, and why are these two representations equivalent?

If possible, explain it as simply as possible, assuming minimal to non-existent familiarity with Schur complements, generalized inverses, and generalized eigenvalue decompositions.

Comment: The statement $B \in \mathcal R(A)$ does not make sense unless $B$ is a column vector. However, the condition $\mathcal R(B) \subseteq \mathcal R(A)$ is indeed equivalent to the condition $(I - AA^g)B = 0$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Thanks. Could you explain, please? (In reasonably elementary terms.)

Comment: I can write something more complete, but maybe this is enough: in a nutshell, $AA^g$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal R(A)$, so $I - AA^g$ is the projection onto its complement.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Thanks. This helps. If you could explain why $AA^g$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{R}(A)$, it would be great. Or should I post a separate question for it?

Comment: I don't think it would be necessary to ask a new question. For what it's worth, Wikipedia [states this fact here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Projectors). If you want a proof that this holds, then please explain which definition of the MP generalized inverse you prefer. For instance, it is pretty quick to show that this projector property holds using the SVD characterization of the generalized inverse

Comment: @BenGrossmann: You know what, I'm satisfied for the time being with Wikipedia's statement of this fact. Thanks!

Comment: @cineel: Thanks. I've corrected this problem. $\mathcal{R}(A)$ is $A$'s **column** space. $\mathcal{R}$ is short for **range**, not **rows**.

Comment: @cineel: Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is wrong to call $A^g$ **the** generalised inverse of $A$, because generalised inverses in general are not unique.

However, since $AA^gA=A$, the matrix $AA^g$ is always idempotent. As such, it represents a (possibly non-orthogonal) projection. If $A$ is $n\times n$, then from
$$
A\mathbb R^n=AA^gA\mathbb R^n\subseteq AA^g\mathbb R^n\subseteq A\mathbb R^n,
$$
we obtain $AA^gR^n=A\mathbb R^n$. Hence $AA^g$ has the same rank as $A$. In turn,
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{nullity}(I-AA^g)
&=\operatorname{rank}(AA^g)\quad\text{(because $AA^g$ is a projection)}\\
&=\operatorname{rank}(A).
\end{aligned}
This, together with the equality $(I-AA^g)A=0$, imply that the null space of $I-AA^g$ is precisely the column space of $A$. Hence the condition $(I-AA^g)B=0$ means that the column space of $B$ lies inside the column space of $A$. In other words, $B=AR$ for some matrix $R$.

Therefore, what Wikipedia says can be rephrased as follows: a real symmetric matrix $X=\pmatrix{A&B\\ B^T&C}$ is positive semidefinite if and only if

1. $A\succeq0$,
2. $\operatorname{range}(B)\subseteq\operatorname{range}(A)$, i.e., $B=AR$ for some matrix $R$, and
3. $C-R^TAR\succeq0$.

For necessity, if $X\succeq0$, clearly $A\succeq0$. Suppose $\operatorname{range}(B)\not\subseteq\operatorname{range}(A)$. Then $By\not\in\operatorname{range}(A)=(\ker A)^\perp$ for some vector $y$. Therefore there exists some $x\in\ker A$ such that $x^TBy\ne0$. If we keep $y$ fixed and scale $x$ by a large factor of an appropriate sign, we can make $x^TBy$ a large negative number. Hence
$$
\pmatrix{x^T&y^T}\pmatrix{A&B\\ B^T&C}\pmatrix{x\\ y}=2x^TBy+y^TCy<0,
$$
which is a contradiction to the positive semidefiniteness of $X$. So, we must have $\operatorname{range}(B)\subseteq\operatorname{range}(A)$, i.e. $B=AR$ for some matrix $R$. Finally, $C-R^TAR$ must be positive semidefinite because $X$ is [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to
$$
\pmatrix{I&0\\ -R^T&I}\pmatrix{A&AR\\ R^TA&C}\pmatrix{I&-R\\ 0&I}=\pmatrix{A&0\\ 0&C-R^TAR}.
$$
This congruence relation also proves the sufficiency of $(1)-(3)$.